# Sending number of parameters from facebook to my server

Tags: java, facebook, jsp, notifications, href

I have a Facebook app which sends her responses to my server hard coded.
My server which is a tomcat recieve the response (a Facebook notification).

I want that an user who use my app will get the notification and when he will click on the notification he will recieve a index.jsp page from my server.

i send the notification and added href that i would like to use that my server recieve:

```
  var messageToSend = "https://graph.facebook.com" + id + ... +
            +**"&href=?username=" + userName + "&userid="+ userId** + "&template=" +
            notificationContent + "&method=POST&format=json";
```

I would like to get in the server side the userId and userName.

In the server side i wrote:

```
String userName = request.getParameter("username"); 
String userId = request.getParameter("userid");
```

i got the userName but the userId is null.

How should i send more than one parameter to my server?

Comment: Are you posting to `/USER ID` ? If so, why? it's not clear what you're doing here - you also shouldn't include User IDs in URLs - why not use some specific identifier for the link and look up your own database to get the name and ID?

Comment: I am sending a Facebook notification to friends of the logged user. I need the id in order to get user's picture. I don't understand how can i get two parameters. i get always only one parameter and the second is null.....